# Getting error that method is not found although method is being run

Tags: java

I have the following bean:

```
package com.company.test;

public class EventFileBean 
{
   public EventFileBean()
   {
       System.out.println("testing... inside EventFileBean");
   }
}
```

It's registered in my **xml** file:

```
<managed-bean>
    <managed-bean-name>eventFileBean</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>com.company.test.EventFileBean</managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>view</managed-bean-scope>
</managed-bean>
```

I'm calling it with:

```
<p:commandButton value="#{msg.yes}" ajax="false" 
                 action="#{eventFileBean.eventFileBean}" 
                 styleClass="stdButton greenButton" oncomplete="confirmation.hide()"/>
```

It crashes with error `" javax.el.MethodNotFoundException: /workshop/editWorkshop.xhtml @86,221 action="#{eventFileBean.eventFileBean}"`, however it prints out the message `"testing... inside EventFileBean"`, so it must have found the method.

Can anyone tell me what's wrong or what else needs to be setup?

Answer (score 0):

Your method `EventFileBean` is a special method as it has the same name as your class: it is the Constructor of the class and for this reason not recognized by that name.

Also, I'm not sure if the capitalization makes a difference: Your method starts with an uppercase letter, while in your xml you search for a method with lowercase letter in the beginning. As Java is case sensitive, these are not the same.

Rename the method to something else than the class name. Maybe just using a lowercase letter as the first letter already works, otherwise try a completely different name.

Comment: I already tried giving the method a different name. When I did that, it still crashed but would not even print the message "testing... inside EventFileBean". So in the first instance, it did call the constructor, but in the second instance, it didn't. Also, my code in the xml is the same convention as other code there, which do not have a problem.

Comment: The message is printed because the constructor is automatically called by Java when the object is created. The message being printed in the constructor does not have anything to do with your configuration in that case.

Comment: I've fixed it. Earlier when I renamed the constructor to another name, it still crashed, but this time I left the constructor there and created a second method with a different name which I called instead. Now it works.